# Easier way for distributing elements of list to a new pandas DataFrame column in a specific ratio conditional on other column values of same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-science

I have a pandas DataFrame `df` with multiple columns. Now I want to add a new column based on other column values. I found many answers for this on stack that includes `np.where` and `np.select`. However, in my case, for every if condition (every if/elif/else block), the new column has to choose among 3 values with a specific ratio. For example,

```
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    if(df.iloc[i]['col1']==x):
        df.iloc[i]['new_col']= choose one value between l=['a','b','c'] in 0.3,0.3,0.4 ratio
```

that is, for all rows satisfying the condition in the `if` statement, the elements of list `l` should be distributed in the above mentioned ratio to new column.

- The current way I am doing is, split the `df` into multiple sub data frames `df_sub` for each `if-else` condtional statement. Next creating a list using `np.random.choices(l,df_sub.shape[0],p=[0.3,0.3,0.4)` where `l=['a','b','c']`. Add `l` to `df_sub` as new column and then join all those sub data frames along `axis=0`.
- I want to know if there is simpler way to accomplish this task instead of dividing and joining data frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
s = df['col1'] == x
df.loc[s, 'new_col'] = np.random.choice(['a','b','c'], 
                                        size=s.sum(), 
                                        p=[0.3,0.3,0.4])
```